# Filtering in flex AdvancedDataGrid using input text

Tags: apache-flex, filtering, advanceddatagrid

I have a advancedDatagrid with column headers having input text boxes for filtering.The column is filtered according to input text when I use characters as data inside that column.But when I use numbers in the column field,filtering does not happen.Can anyone tell me what went wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Can you post the code for the filtering method you use for the number fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are from Mahindra city.